# ASP.NET Chart control (sending EMail with embedded chart control image)

Tags: asp.net

I am using the asp.net chart control and I am happy with it. My client is now asking me if I can add an email button to my web page an send off an email with the chart included in it. Any ideas how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The chart component actually generates an image when the chart is requested.  It then either persists this image to the file system or simply holds it in memory.  That part is configurable.

You can have it generate the chart, then grab the file reference from it.  From there you have two choices.  Either have your email refer to the the file by it's url reference or embed it within the actual email itself.  That's also configurable by the mail client.

Answer (score 2):

You could save the image somewhere and load it and embed in the mail as follows:

```
        private void SendMail()
        {
            //Your mail body is created with help of a StringBuilder which will contain the img tag:
            //Suppose the mailContent is the StringBuilder object and has the html body etc already appended....
            //you would need to append something like following:

            //mailContent.Append("<td><img src=\"cid:IMAGE_ID\"></td>");
            //string body = mailContent.ToString();


            string smtpServer = "mailhost.my.domain.net";
            string emailFrom = "blah.blah@blah.com";
            string emailTo = "yoyo@yoyo.com";


            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(emailFrom, emailTo, "TestMail...", body);

            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            //Adding attachments by loading from file 
            Attachment item = new Attachment("Images/Logo.JPG");
            item.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
            item.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
            item.ContentId = "IMAGE_ID";
            item.ContentType.MediaType = "image/jpeg";
            item.ContentType.Name = "Logo.JPG";

            msg.Attachments.Add(item);

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
            client.Send(msg);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the chart data and create a link to the page that would load the data, or you could get the HTML that created the page and load it into the email.  Not every user views HTML is emails so might be safer to send them a link to the page that can chart the data.